# The textbook of Abelian varieties included Grothendieck’s semi-stable reduction Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

I would like to learn abelian varieties, semi-stable abelian varieties, and the proof of  Grothendieck’s semi-stable reduction Theorem. I have briefly learned abstract algebra, category theory, algebraic number theory, scheme theory but I only know the definition of an abelian variety so I'm looking for a book that starts from there. Is there a book that proves Grothendieck ’s semi-stable reduction Theorem, starting with the definition of abelian varieties? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Qing Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*